# Partial search in Sitecore Multilist with Search type of field

Tags: sitecore-client

I am using the multi-list with search field in my project. I have many items to render within (approx 400), so it's not possible for the users to scroll through and choose a specific one.
There is one item named "Gracy-Timoth" when I type in the search box "gra" it's not giving me the "gracy-timoth" in fact it's showing all empty, but when I pass the complete name "gracy", it gives me the result.
I want to get result on typing the partial words such as "gra" for "gracy-timoth".

I am using the below query as Datasource for multi-list with search.

`StartSearchLocation={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}&TemplateFilter={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`

here I am passing the correct guid accordingly. Any suggestion on this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for part of the words in the searchbox by using the `*` character. For example in your case it would be `gra*`.

Comment: but I want it to be dynamic like I am not passing any static keyword in the query. it's taking from the search box. So it would be great if somehow I can get the value of that search box then I can use the below query 

`StartSearchLocation={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}&TemplateFilter={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}&Filter=Display name:*value from searchbox*`

Comment: @GauravSoni you can just use the `gra*` in the searchbox. You don’t need to hardcode this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. I think by default sitecore is doing an exact search of the text entered in the search box (for example test1), if you take a look in the saerch log it will have a query like this:

```
?q=((((-_group:(66a1aed3af694bcab42171c1e6331a98)  *:*) AND (((_content:(test1) OR _name:(test1) OR _displayname:(test1)) AND _path:(110d559fdea542ea9c1c8a5df7e70ef9)) AND _latestversion:(True))) AND _datasource:(sitecore)) AND _latestversion:(1))&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)&wt=xml
```

Unfortunately there is no OOTB way to change the search query unless specifying * in the search box like tes*. One option would be to try to append this * to the text from javascript when sitecore makes the search call, the field is using the js file /sitecore/shell/Controls/BucketList/BucketList.js, you can take a look at the event `$('filterBox' + self.clientId).observe('keyup', function () {`.

If you want to change the query from code you would need to change the existing implementation. When performing a search you will see that it is calling `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx`, which is built in the `Sitecore.Buckets.Client` dll in the namespace `ItemBuckets.Services.Search`.

```
namespace ItemBuckets.Services
{
  /// <summary>Search End Point</summary>
  public class Search : SearchHttpTaskAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState
  {
```

This class inherits from the `SearchHttpTaskAsyncHandler` which has a method that extracts the query from the parameters:

```
public void ExtractSearchQuery(NameValueCollection parameters)
{
   case "fromBucketListField":
      if (parameters[index] != "*")
      {
         this.searchQuery.Add(new SearchStringModel()
         {
            Type = "text",
            Value = parameters[index],
            Operation = "must"
          });
          continue;
       }
```

You would need to built your own implementation of Search.ashx and you can override the path specified in the field code source in `Sitecore.Buckets.FieldTypes.BucketList`:

```
public class BucketList : SearchList
{
   protected override string ScriptParameters => string.Format("'{0}'", (object) string.Join("', '", (object) this.ID,     
    (object) this.ClientID, (object) this.PageNumber, (object) "/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx"
```

You can take a look at an example of a custom implementation here http://sitecoreexperiences.blogspot.com/2015/08/serving-non-sitecore-data-in-sitecore_51.html